# Populate Two Columns in single collection_select Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**View**

```
<%= collection_select(@table, "sp", @pops, "col2", "col2", {:prompt => "Select one"}) %>
```

**Controller**

```
@pops = Table.find(:all, :conditions=>{:col1 => "xyz"}, :order=> 'col2', :select=> 'DISTINCT col2')
```

This is my existing code. I am collecting a values in a column2 and populating it.
Existing populating values as (col2a,col2b,col2c)

Now, I wish to populate two columns col2 and col3 in a single collection_select. I wish to populate like
(col2a[col3a],col2b[col3b],col2c[col3c]). Kindly give me the idea to populate two columns in single collection select

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Table model, add the following method (name it whatever suits your app, I name it "combined_value")

```
def combined_value
  "#{self.col2}[#{self.col3}]"
end
```

In the view, the collection_select is as follows

```
<%= collection_select(@table, "sp", @pops, "combined_value", "col2", {:prompt => "Select one"}) %>
```

The generated HTML will look like this

```
<select name="table[sp]">
  <option value="">Select one</option>
  <option value="col2a[col3a]">col2a</option>
  <option value="col2b[col3b]">col2b</option>
  <option value="col2c[col3c]">col2c</option>
</select>
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly... But it prints only col2a, col2b.

Comment: When I replace col2 and combined value positions in collection_select,,, it works great.... God thanks....

Comment: How I can include special characters in model. eg. "#{self.col2}&[ty]=#{self.col3}]". "&" and "=" characters are produced as encoded data. How I can decode those data and present in params[:id]?

Comment: In your controller, you can do this to unescape those characters: CGI::unescapeHTML(params[:id]).

Comment: No... I need to apply without help of any modules. its possible in html? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

So you use col2 as keys and col3 as values? `Hash[*col2.zip(col3)]`

Comment: Where I can apply "Hash[*col2.zip(col3)]"? View or Controller? Kindly mention it in above query,,,

Comment: I've got no clue about `collection_select`, but with [formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), see Usage lowest quite at the end of the section.

Answer (score -1):

In the Table model, add the following method (name it whatever suits your app, I name it "combined_value")

def combined_value
  "#{self.col2}[#{self.col3}]"
end

In the view, the collection_select is as follows

<%= collection_select(@table, "sp", @pops, "col2", "combined_value", {:prompt => "Select one"}) %>

The generated HTML will look like this

Select one
  col2a[col3a]
  col2b[col3b]
  col2c[col3c]

Is this I want... My questions may confused someone... Sorry for that... God thanks to Hoa... Its Working as my requirement...

Comment: You should accept the correct answer, not repeat the correct answer and accept your version of it!